# grunt dalekjs-task does not close chrome after execution

Tags: javascript, testing, gruntjs, dalekjs

Hey I have following grunt task:

```
module.exports = {
  options: {
    browser: ['chrome'],
    reporter: ['console', 'html'],
    dalekfile: false
  },

  gui: {
    src: [
      'tests/gui/Login.js',
      'tests/gui/Navbar.js'
    ]
  }
};
```

The problem is that the dalek task does not kill the chrome instance after executing the test.

Any ideas why?

EDIT: This happens only when an error is found during the tests.

System specs: win7, 64 bit
Dalek specs: cli tools --> 0.0.4, dalekjs local install --> 0.0.8
cheers izocan

Answer (score 0):

That is interesting, can you specify your environment & open up an issue over at github; I suppose it is a bug. Please also add a reduced testcase. One test & the stripped down contents of your Gruntfile, so that we can reproduce this. Also please post the link to your newly created issue here, so people can keep track.

Comment: hey sebastian, you can view the detailed description on [github](https://github.com/dalekjs/grunt-dalek/issues/12)